# Confusion with Computing Probabilities of a Normal Distribution without the Integral

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, python, tensorflow

How does this code is calculating the probability of Normal distribution without calculating the integral

```
oneDivSqrtTwoPI = 1 / math.sqrt(2*math.pi)
   def tf_normal(y, mu, sigma):
   result = tf.subtract(y, mu)
   result = tf.divide(result, sigma)
   result = -tf.square(result)/2
   return tf.divide(tf.exp(result), sigma)*oneDivSqrtTwoPI
```

tf_normal(0 , 0, 1) = 0.398

The problem here is that, this code is giving me probability of y being = 0 is 0.398. To calculate the probability of a continuous random variable, you need to integrate the PDF over a small region to get the probability. Here, it is return probability straight from the PDF. What I am missing here?

Also, to verify this code, I also used tf.distributions.Normal and it returned the same result.

Comment: I suppose we'd need to know what programming language you are using here.

Comment: Python. But this question is kind of language independant

Comment: You should put that in the actual text of your question.  For example, "how does this "python code..."  It's not language independent.   `tf.subtract` is not a universal function.

Comment: It's not computing a probability: it's implementing the definition of the Normal *probability density.*  If you're not completely sure of that, evaluate your function at (say) `y=0`, `mu=0`, and `sigma=0.1`: you will obtain a number greater than 1.

Comment: I understand that, the code is literally computing the PDF of the normal. But again, i looked at the tf.distributions.Normal  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Normal Plugged in the required values and called the dist.prob function. it gave me same values

Comment: In R, `dnorm` (without additional parameters) is the standard normal PDF $\varphi,$ so `dnorm(0)` returns  $\varphi(0) = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} = 0.3989423.$ Also, `pnorm` is the std normal CDF $\Phi,$ so `pnorm(0)` returns $\Phi(0) = 0.5.$ The R function `pnorm` is ultimately based on numerical integration because $\Phi$ can't be expressed in closed form. [But there's a very good algorithmic approx. of $\Phi$ due to Michael Wichura, carefully vetted by comparison with results from num. integ. that's widely used in statistical computing]. // You need to check _Python_ syntax for $\varphi$ and $\Phi.$